# Yfinance Auto Adjust and Progress

Tags: yfinance

I am following a tutorial on pulling stock data from yahoo finance. He is using
`yfinance.download(stock tickers, auto_adjust=False, progress = False)`.
What do auto adjust and progress mean? I tried to google them but found no answers.

Answer (score 2):

Auto Adjust will overwrite the `Close` price by `Adj Close`.
Progress will show a progress bar.