# Yfinance.download() Auto Adjust=True - What does it actually do?

Tags: python, yfinance, stock-data

What does `auto_adjust=True` do while downloading the historical data of a stock using the **yfinance** module in Python? I found no official documentation.

[algotrading101](https://algotrading101.com/learn/yfinance-guide/) says it adjusts all OHLC (Open/High/Low/Close) prices. However, [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62622996/yfinance-auto-adjust-and-progress) says it will only adjust the closing price.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 3):

The code for the [`yfinance`](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance) library is available on GitHub. We can inspect [`auto_adjust` in the codebase](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/blob/0713d9386769b168926d3959efd8310b56a33096/yfinance/utils.py#L445-L462).

A quick glance at the relevant code linked above shows that `auto_adjust` makes adjustments to each of the Open, High, and Low prices based on the ratio of Adj Close and Close data provided by the upstream source.

Answer (score 1):

Usually,

> auto_adjust=True

in yfinance automatically adjusts historical stock prices for splits and dividends. This ensures that the price data reflects the true performance of the stock over time.

However, I'm working on a project that involves analyzing historical forex price data.

I came across a helpful and simple blog post that explains how to use the yfinance library in Python to download forex data. It doesn't need "auto_adjust=True" for downloading the data.

Here is where you can find the blog:
https://blog.quantinsti.com/download-forex-price-data-yfinance-library-python/

The blog post provides clear instructions on:

1. Installing the yfinance library
2. Downloading daily and
   minute-frequency forex data
3. Plotting the downloaded data as a time
   series

I followed the steps in the blog post and successfully downloaded the data I needed.